# android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar not installed

Tags: android

i created a test project with demo tab activity. I have not written a single line of code, everything has been generated by eclips juno and i got -The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar error massage ,how to fix it

Comment: I would strongly suggest you move to Android Studio if possible. Eclipse is lagging behind more and more. It's much easier as well as more streamlined.

Comment: I have worked with both Eclipse and Android Studio and in all honesty, Android Studio is much better. IntelliJ is another alternative which I worked with once.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your SDK support library.
Often I've encountered errors even with auto-generated classes because my libraries were not updated.